# How to select particular id from the json format ...?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How do I select particular specific data from the json format in the ionic project?

How to select the id from the specific data in the json format?
How to get the value from the id of the selected product and display it particularly?

How can I get the data from the json array by ID?

`public product_data=[{`
`product_id:'1',`
`product_image: "assets/img/rhoite.jpg",`
`{`
`product_id:'2',`
`product_image: "assets/img/smtz.jpg",`
`];`

Comment: you want to filter data as per selected ID from the existing JSON data?

Comment: Just take a look at the `filter` method [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). That should get you started.

Comment: yes pradeep jain i have json data upto the 30 and want to display it as per the specific selection on the id and show it's data..!

Comment: @jayshah please refer to my answer below, you can choose either method from two mentioned

Comment: okay pradeep jain thanks for helping me while doing it if any error come's will let' you know soon..!

Comment: @PardeepJain it's not working, what i have to do is select from the json format and show that's speicific id's data only in the ionic 3 so, how it is possible..?

Comment: @jayshah so after finding data as I suggested in my answer, bind to some variable and display it in your application, Thanks!

Comment: @PradeepJain as i am new to ionic i don't know here to mention where would these all case's will be call..?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Filter operator -

```
product_data.filter(ele => ele.product_id == '1')
```

PS: You can change the key/value pair with whatever you want to search/filter.

Or **alternatively**, you can use **`Array.find`** method as well, which will return only object if found, like below -

```
product_data.find(ele => ele.product_id == '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the desired data using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let product_data=[{ product_id:'1', product_image: "assets/img/rhoite.jpg"}, { product_id:'2', product_image: "assets/img/smtz.jpg"}, ];

let select = 2

let op = product_data.filter(e=> e.product_id == select)

console.log(op)
```